# Architecture of Nvidia driver open source code

Tags: gpu, linux-device-driver, nvidia, gpgpu

I was looking at the half open - half closed source code of Nvidia's Linux device driver. I am trying to understand how it manages user space memory allocation on the GPU side for CUDA programs. I think I have found the module responsible for it (uvm8_pmm_gpu.c, which interacts with PMA which is closed source. PMA is physical memory allocator and PMM is physical memory manager), which seems to have a sort of buddy allocator but I can't make the driver execute this code no matter what CUDA code I run. So my question is:

1) Has someone looked at the code of Nvidia GPU drivers? Is there a wiki somewhere where someone has posted about it's architecture?

2) Do anyone knows how the driver manages memory allocation?